# Colors not being showed on separated objects

Tags: rendering, texturing, uv, shaders

I am trying to make this house front elevation and separated the objects which need granite texture and got them in a separate collection. But I am not able to apply the texture can somebody help me out. Here are the reference picture and the .blend file. [Blender File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OWywjIW-JtG7dq7cC3bDc3MbXnNSR44A/view?usp=sharing)
[Reference photo](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1F6byGsOYLyYm0Of4O5sDdRApgVpAIdw-/view?usp=sharing)

Here is a reference to my problem. [image]

If you can pls send me the working model with colors within my design or completely your own. Pls, help me.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: First thing your object has a bad topology with overlapping faces, you need to completely redo it correctly

Comment: Do you think there is no way to do it without redoing it? i need it really fast.

Comment: what about selecting your object, TAB, A, then choose your granite material, then tap assign -> is that what you want?

Comment: But how do I do it? if you can pls help me out.